# insert on duplicate key update batch with separate update columns

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, query-optimization, batch-query

I have a situation where I have a table `(col1 (pk), col2, col3, col4)` and a set of records which I need to insert into a table and on duplicate key update them. I would like to do a batch query to speed things up. However, `col4` doesn't have a `NOT NULL` constraint. The problem arises when I want to update with records `(val1, val2, val3, None), (val4, val5, val6, val7)`. For the first record, I don't want column 4 to be updated (If `(val1, val2, val3, val8)` existed in DB I wouldn't want to override val8 because None would signify lack of value as opposed to explicit setting to Null). However, for the second record, I would want to update `col4` because an explicit value is passed. This would be fine with one record where I would just set the update columns to be `col2, col3,` and not `col4`, but I want to batch this query and would need to have `col4`update when a value is passed for it and not update when I don't have a value. I would logically need something like given below.

```
INSERT INTO table1
  (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES
  ('val1', 'val2', 'val3'), ON DUP KEY UPDATE col2, col3
  ('val5', 'val6', 'val7', 'val8'), ON DUP KEY UPDATE col2, col3, col4
  ('val9', 'val10', 'val11') ON DUP KEY UPDATE col2, col3
```

Clearly this can be done by just making it a series of separate statements, but I would like to find a way to batch this. Is there any way this, or a different method, can be done in sql?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  We need to see _exactly_ what unique key(s) you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `on duplicate key update` part of the insert, you can refer to the inserted values with `values`.  You can use `coalesce` to preserve the pre-update value in case of `null`:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES
    ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', null)
,   ('val5', 'val6', 'val7', 'val8')
,   ('val9', 'val10', 'val11', null)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    col1 = values(col1)
,   col2 = values(col2)
,   col3 = values(col3)
,   col4 = coalesce(values(col4), col4)
```

[Example on SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d36d88/1/0)

In reply to your comment, you can set `null` explicitly with a `case`:

```
,   col4 = case values(col4) 
           when 'None' then null 
           else coalesce(values(col4), col4)
           end
```

The obvious risk here is that you can no longer update to None :)

Comment: Is there any way to modify this a little to also allow for explicit setting of 
 null? I could imagine having a value for col4 as 'None' locally which means I don't have this value don't update (by using coalesce) but also as 'Null' which explicitly means update the column to null. The latter wouldn't work with this solution right?

Comment: Sure, you could use a case for that. I'll add an example to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the thing that you are looking for?

```
INSERT INTO table1
  (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES
  ('val1', 'val2', 'val3', null)
  ('val5', 'val6', 'val7', 'val8')
  ('val9', 'val10', 'val11', null)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  col2 = values(col2),
  col3 = values(col3),
  col4 = coalesce(values(col4), col4)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

The number of fields in VALUES must be the same as in INSERT. But you can just pass `NULL` for the `col4` and use COALESCE in the UPDATE part.

```
INSERT INTO table1
  (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES
  ('val1', 'val2',  'val3',  NULL),
  ('val5', 'val6',  'val7',  'val8'),
  ('val9', 'val10', 'val11', NULL)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  col2 = VALUES(col2),
  col3 = VALUES(col3),
  col4 = COALESCE(VALUES(col4), col4)
```